# How should I certify data for my user in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain up and running with several channels.

What I do is certifying data, in my case, certifying that my customer use green energy.

How should I provide a visual proof for my user that data is coming from the blockchain? I need to materialize it visually. Like a button that will check a hash, or something like that. But I have no idea what should be checked.

Any idea ?

EDIT:

Here is the data related to a transaction ID that I get from hyperledger explorer

```
Transaction ID: 452882aabb96448fea539cbb5d9bd7e04db1d24fb460813d14d501cb1bcxxxxx
Validation Code:    VALID
Payload Proposal Hash:  d20c9331d72a30408dd6de81351ffbdccbd9392bfb46472e88ab1a93328xxxxx
Creator MSP:    solMSP
Endorser:   {"solMSP"}
Chaincode Name: main
Type:   ENDORSER_TRANSACTION
Time:   2021-04-03T15:50:03.576Z
Reads:  ...
Writes:  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example,if you want to certifying Tom use green energy,

first,you need upload info "Tom use green energy" to your chain,then you will get response

```
//response format,if success ,you have upload info upon your chain
type Response struct {
    Proposal         *fab.TransactionProposal
    Responses        []*fab.TransactionProposalResponse
    TransactionID    fab.TransactionID
    TxValidationCode pb.TxValidationCode
    ChaincodeStatus  int32
    Payload          []byte
}
```

then you can save this data (for instance `TransactionID`) into your own application database ,then you can certifying "Tom use green energy" by query this TransactionID from your own application(OR you can directly query from your chain,but I think it my be slow than query directly from your app).

Comment: Ok, so I will have a transaction ID associated to a data. I will say: This is the transaction ID associated with your green consumption at this time. But I could also print this without using blockchain, and generating fake transactionID, for the user, it would be the same no ? In hyperledger explorer, indeed, I can get all the data I have put at the end of the question. But is it enough to certify a data from the user point of view ?

Comment: Of course, you can generate a fake ID,but in your chain there does not exist date  associated to the fake ID

Comment: but imagine I just have a time series DB with no blockchain technology, in which for each data, I add a fake transaction ID at saving time. For each transaction ID, I will have a data?  For the user, it will be the same, as he doesn't have access to the technological stack.

Comment: as you said，I think an user must first get an indentity from fabric CA,then he can access the blockchain network,and he can use this identity to check data whether obtain from blockchain

Comment: ok, it makes sense, even if a regular user won't be able to connect to the blockchain, because he doesn't even know terminals exists.